# Change a currently non used class implementation at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, runtime

I have a C++ code being executing on a big file(~15 GB). The code has two phases and the first phase will take much time to finish. But in the mean time I have got a better implementation technique for its phase 2, and don't want to restart the whole execution right from start. The two phases are categorized by the two classes actually being used. Take an idea from it:

```
Parser.parse(filePath);    // phase one
Processor.processAndLog(); // phase two
```

So, is there some method to change the implementation of Processor class before it starts executing? The end of phase 1 (or even how much it has completed) can be distinguished from some time to time messages(say logs) I have printed.

Comment: well if there is some, none is recommended

Comment: It will be helpful if you mention them.

Comment: binary modify the executable in orfer to intercept the wrong call and call something else.

Answer (score 0):

If `Processor.processAndLog` is a member function pointer than you can change it anytime before it's called.

An alternative is to have Processor.processAndLog be a wrapper function for other functions - a dispatch function.

There's also the matter of hooking a function. there's a library called [detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). Use this only if you can't change the source code if the program.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this correctly: You have a program that is currently running, but which hasn't yet gotten to executing the code in a particular class. And you want to find a way to update it to use a new version of the code for that class without stopping the program.

In theory that could be done. But in practice, it's likely to be far more trouble than it's worth, especially if this is a one-time need. C++ was not designed for this kind of thing. It's not like there is simply human-readable source code sitting in the process's memory that could be overwritten easily.

Doing this correctly would almost certainly take a significant amount of time and effort, most likely involving a lot of experimenting and trail-and-error. If you get something about it wrong (which is likely the first time) then you've probably just corrupted your process and your results, and would thus need to restart it anyway.

I don't know how long your process is currently taking, but trying to figure how to accomplish this idea might very well take more time than just restarting the process after building the new version of the program.